# Error while reading multipart response || Response code: 200

Tags: react-native

I am using React native for my mobile application. Its almost done and ready for publishing. But, last few days I am facing this strange error when I try to launch my working app from the editor. I am not sure this is because of Internet issue or not. Can someone please share your ideas regarding this?

Thanks in Advance[image]

Comment: This is mainly Internet issue.

Comment: i am having the same issue but my internet speed is so good, any body knows how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

I also experience a similar error, I simply changed the internet connectivity and reloaded the app came back to life.

Answer (score 1):

This type of error occurs only when you have network issue . Please check network connection and once restart your application you might get success.

Answer (score 0):

for this error check your receive response on screen , that's cause for receive unexpected Response , you can Check response with `console.log()` for that .